# Ionic Contacts problem getting all numbers from a contact

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, native, contacts

I hope you are well.

I have a problem with Ionic Contacts.

I am getting all the contacts with my code right now but I need to extract all the phone numbers that a contact has. For exemple if John has 3 phone numbers, I would like to display them in my list, right now I can display only 1. How can I achieve that ?

Code :

```
loadContacts() {
    let options = {
      filter: "",
      multiple: true,
      hasPhoneNumber: true,
    };
    this.contacts.find(["*"], options).then((contacts: Contact[]) => {
      this.myContacts = contacts;
      console.log("Contacts:", contacts);
    });
  }
```

```
<ion-button (click)="loadContacts()" expand="full"
          >Load Contacts</ion-button
        >
        <ion-list *ngFor="let c of myContacts">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label
              >{{c.name.givenName}} {{c.name.familyName}}
              <p>
                {{c.phoneNumbers[ 0 ].value}}
              </p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ojetdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

I have prepared a demo to show multiple contacts in a template:
I am not focusing on the contact model here. You may tweak the contact model as you prefer.

Template:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
    Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>

<!-- <ion-button (click)="loadContacts()" expand="full">Load Contacts</ion-button> -->

<ion-list *ngFor="let c of myContacts">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{c.givenName}} {{c.familyName}}
            <p>
                {{c.phoneNumbers}}
            </p>
        </ion-label>
    <hr>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
<hr><hr>
<h3>Do you want to break the contacts more?</h3>

<ion-list *ngFor="let c of myContacts">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>{{c.givenName}} {{c.familyName}}
            <p *ngFor="let p of c.phoneNumbers">
                {{p}}
            </p>
        </ion-label>
    <hr>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

export interface Contact {
  givenName: String;
  familyName: String;
  phoneNumbers: Array<Number>;
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  myContacts: Contact[] = [
    {
      givenName: "X",
      familyName: "FX",
      phoneNumbers: [1111111, 2222222, 333333]
    },
    {
      givenName: "Y",
      familyName: "FY",
      phoneNumbers: [44444, 5555, 6666]
    },
    {
      givenName: "Z",
      familyName: "FZ",
      phoneNumbers: [77777, 8888, 9999]
    }
  ];
}
```

Additional Scenario:
*Right now I get the name and all the phones of the contact which is great but if a contact has 2-3-4 phone numbers I would like to show them separately , for exemple in a list to be John Doe with first phone number and after again John Doe with the second phone number and after John Doe with the 3rd phone number and so on , because I want to add them in a checklist after so I can choose which number I will select*

You may do it this way, just tweak the ionic checkboxes:
[Live Example 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ojetdz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<h3>Do you want to break the contacts more?</h3>

<ion-list *ngFor="let c of myContacts">
    <ion-item>
        <div *ngFor="let p of c.phoneNumbers">
            <ion-label>Name: {{c.givenName}} {{c.familyName}}
        </ion-label><br>
    <ion-checkbox checked>Phone Number: {{p}}</ion-checkbox>
    <br><br>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Its working @Ashish Kumar Jaryal , really appreciate. I just have 1 more question if you have a bit of time to help me with this too would be amazing. Right now I get the name and all the phones of the contact which is great but if a contact has 2-3-4 phone numbers I would like to show them separately , for exemple in a list to be John Doe with first phone number and after again John Doe with the second phone number and after John Doe with the 3rd phone number and so on , because I want to add them in a checklist after so I can choose which number I will select. Do you have any idea? Ty

Comment: @tirbushonn23 : I have updated my answer. Please check and mark my answer as accepted if it solved your problem.